# Sonar-Runner job can't delete sonar_lock file

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm getting this message while running a sonarqube analysis using Jenkins.

Log.

```
Colorizer Sensor (wrapped) -> CPD Sensor (wrapped)

17:58:10.957 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (wrapped)

17:58:10.962 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=5ms

17:58:10.962 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor

17:58:10.962 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=0ms

17:58:10.963 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor

17:58:10.963 WARN  -
**********************************************************************************


**17:58:10.963 WARN  - *                Use MSBuild 14 to get the best analysis results**

17:58:10.963 WARN  - * The use of MSBuild 12 or the sonar-runner to analyze C# projects is DEPRECATED *


17:58:10.963 WARN  -
********************************************************************************
**

17:58:10.976 INFO  - Analysis report generated in D:\jenkins\workspace\Project\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\batch-report

**17:58:10.981 DEBUG - Couldn't delete lock file: D:\jenkins\workspace\Project\Project\.sonar_lock java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:**
```

**2 QUESTIONS**

1. Whats this sonar_lock file, why is it created? I've a succeded build where this file is not on the log.
2. I'm sure I'm using MSbuild 14, why am I still getting this message about MSbuild 12?

Any help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is 'D:\' a local drive or a remote mount ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1** Lock file is used too see if it is running already (avoiding two simultaneous runs as second will fail)

**In this case** log message is saying that file doesn't exist so it cannot be deleted (as expected on a first run) with a message that might be improved as it should say something like *Cannot find lock file, creating it...* (Sounds a bug in Sonar code). As you can see the message is DEBUG level so seems not important if build is successful.

If I were you I would change Sonar verbosity level to something higher that doesn't show DEBUG.

**Answer 2** I would need the full log to help here. Not sure if it is a generic "Warn" message from Sonar or if Sonar is really detecting  MSBuild 12. **Could you publish full log**?